# Best way to group adjacent array items by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

Assume we have an array of values:

```
[5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3]
```

What is the best way to group them by value and adjacency. The result should be as follows:

```
[ [5,5], [3], [5], [3,3] ]
```

Of course, I can loop through the source array and look for the next/previous item, and if they are the same, push them to a temporary array that will be then pushed to the resulting array.

But I like to write code in functional way. So maybe there could be a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```js
var result = [5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3].reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    if (prev.length && curr === prev[prev.length - 1][0]) {
        prev[prev.length - 1].push(curr);
    }
    else {
        prev.push([curr]);
    }
    return prev;
}, []);

alert( JSON.stringify(result) );
```

Comment: Some notes on this code: ```prev``` is the portion of the array that has been built up so far, ```curr``` is the element we are looking at. We either add to the last array in the grouped array or start a new one. ```prev.length``` evaluates to false if it 0, which prevents us from accessing index -1 in the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about **performance**, n - complexity [O(n)] is what you'll get (the one iteration that you are talking about).

If you are talking about **memory usage optimization**, maybe you will want to push / pop the objects (not to duplicate them). Or try to organize your input array as an array of arrays when it is first created (e.g. [ [5], [5], [3], [5], [3], [3] ] ) and work only on this array, to shape it to the end-form you are aiming for.

If you want to be more fancy in your implementation, you can try to implement a **recursive function** to process it (but as a general rule of thumb, between two implementations that offer the same performance, the one that is simpler to read is the one you should aim for).

Answer (score 1):

I had a need for the same thing, but grouping by a function of each value (not the values themselves). For example,

```
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 42]
```

to become

```
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6], [7], [8], [9], [10, 42]]
```

given the grouping function

```
function (a) { return a % 2; }
```

One way was to extend @dfsq's method but using a lexicographically scoped `fn_prev` to avoid recomputing the previous `fn(val)`.

```
var fn_prev = null;
myArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
  let fn_curr = fn(val);
  if (!acc.length || fn_curr !== fn_prev) {
    acc.push([val]);
  } else {
    acc[acc.length - 1].push(val);
  }
  fn_prev = fn_curr;
  return acc;
}, []);
```

I felt it was more straightforward to avoid the `.reduce` though:

```
let fn_prev = null;
let acc = [];
for (let val of myArray) {
  let fn_curr = fn(val);
  if (!acc.length || fn_curr !== fn_prev) {
    acc.push([val]);
  } else {
    acc[acc.length - 1].push(val);
  }
  fn_prev = fn_curr;
}
console.log(acc);
```

This can be added to the Array prototype like so:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'groupByAdjacent', {
  value: function(fn) {
    let fn_prev = null;
    let acc = [];
    for (let val of [].concat(this)) {
      let fn_curr = fn(val);
      if (!acc.length || fn_curr !== fn_prev) {
        acc.push([val]);
      } else {
        acc[acc.length - 1].push(val);
      }
      fn_prev = fn_curr;
    }
    return acc;
  }
});
```

And used like this:

```
let x = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 42];
let grouped_x = x.groupByAdjacent(a => a % 2);
console.log(grouped_x);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice use-case for the uncommon `Array.prototype.reduceRight` -

```js
const data =
  [ 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3 ]
  
const groupAdjacent = (a = []) =>
  a.reduceRight
    ( ([ group = [], ...result ], v) =>
        group.length
          ? group[0] === v
              ? [ [ v, ...group ], ...result ] // v matches group
              : [ [ v ], group, ...result ]    // v does not match group
          : [ [ v ], ...result ]               // no group to compare
    , [[]]
    )
        
console.log(groupAdjacent(data))
// [ [ 5, 5 ], [ 3 ], [ 5 ], [ 3, 3 ] ]

console.log(groupAdjacent([]))
// [ [] ]
```

The same process can be described using continuation-passing style -

```js
const data =
  [ 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3 ]
  
const identity = x =>
  x
  
const None =
  Symbol ()
  
const groupAdjacent = ([ v = None, ...more ], k = identity) =>
  v === None
    ? k ([[]])
    : groupAdjacent (more, ([ group, ...result ]) =>
        group.length
          ? group[0] === v
              ? k ([ [ v, ...group ], ...result ]) // v matches group
              : k ([ [ v ], group, ...result ])    // v does not match group
          : k ([ [ v ], ...result ])               // no group to compare
      )
        
console.log(groupAdjacent(data))
// [ [ 5, 5 ], [ 3 ], [ 5 ], [ 3, 3 ] ]

console.log(groupAdjacent([]))
// [ [] ]
```