# Get different arrays from single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have below input array,

```
var temp = ['3_2', '3_2', '3_2', '4_2', '4_2', '5_2', '5_2' ]
```

that, I need to split into temp arrays like below,

```
var temp1 = ['3_2', '3_2', '3_2']

var temp2 = ['4_2', '4_2']

var temp3 = ['5_2', '5_2']
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675688/best-way-to-group-adjacent-array-items-by-value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to group adjacent array items by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675688/best-way-to-group-adjacent-array-items-by-value)

Comment: what will be the  output for var temp = ['3_2', '3_2', '3_1', '4_2', '4_2', '5_2', '5_2' ,'6_1']?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values()` and `.reduce()`:

```js
var temp = ['3_2', '3_2', '3_2', '4_2', '4_2', '5_2', '5_2' ];

var result = Object.values(temp.reduce((a, c) => {
  let [v] = c.split('_');
  a[v] = a[v] || [];
  a[v].push(c);
  return a;
}, {}));

var [temp1, temp2, temp3] = result;

console.log(temp1);
console.log(temp2);
console.log(temp3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object with the references to the variables.

```js
var temp = ['3_2', '3_2', '3_2', '4_2', '4_2', '5_2', '5_2'],
    temp1 = [],
    temp2 = [],
    temp3 = [],
    hash = { 3: temp1, 4: temp2, 5: temp3 };

temp.forEach(v => hash[v[0]].push(v));

console.log(temp1);
console.log(temp2);
console.log(temp3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina, your answer is working but, values in the temp is dynamic , i may get different values in temp array like X_2 in X place i may get 2,3,5, 6, 8, 9 .......

Comment: where do you get the variables like `temp1`, `temp2`, etc from?

Comment: In my application i am getting a large JSON i converted that json to small and posted in Stackoverflow

Comment: that does not answer the question. you asked for assinging some values to a specific set of variables. where do you get them from?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```js
const base = ['3_2', '3_2', '3_2', '4_2', '4_2', '5_2', '5_2'];

const newArrays = base.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  const firstNumber = x.charAt(0);

  // Look if there is an array about the first number
  const index = tmp.findIndex(y => y[0].charAt(0) === firstNumber);

  // If there is no array yet, add one
  if (index === -1) {
    tmp.push([
      x,
    ]);

    return tmp;
  }

  // Push in existing array
  tmp[index].push(x);

  return tmp;
}, []);

console.log(newArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate the array. Add sub arrays if none exists or if current item doesn't fit to current sub-array. Always push the item to the last sub-array. Get the `temp_1/2/3` by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the result of the reduce:

```js
const temp = ['3_2', '3_2', '3_2', '4_2', '4_2', '5_2', '5_2'];

const [temp_1, temp_2, temp_3] = temp.reduce((r, s) => {
  const key = s.split('_')[0];
  
  // if there isn't a sub array, or if the key doesn't fit the sub array, add a new sub array
  if(!r[r.length - 1] || !r[r.length - 1][0].startsWith(key)) {
    r.push([]);
  }
  
  // push to last subarry
  r[r.length - 1].push(s);
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log('temp_1', temp_1);
console.log('temp_2', temp_2);
console.log('temp_3', temp_3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example provided, there are only 3 temp variables, however, in general there can be many variables depending on test case.

You can try following

```js
  var temp = ['3_2', '3_2', '3_2', '4_2', '4_2', '5_2', '5_2' ];


  var counter = 1;
  var map = {};

  temp.forEach(function(item){
    if(map[item]) {
      window["temp" + map[item]].push(item);
    } else {
      window["temp" + counter] = [item];
      map[item] = counter++;
    }
  });

  console.log(temp1);
  console.log(temp2);
  console.log(temp3);
```

Also, in the above illustration, I have used `window`, you can store in an `object` too and then assign them to variables

Comment: wont work for temp = ['3_2', '3_2', '3_1', '4_2', '4_2', '5_2', '5_2' ]

Comment: OP want to seperate out array based on prefix i.e 3_, 4_ etc

Comment: OP has not mentioned this in the question. Though, It is the interpretation by fellow members I guess.

Comment: hmm I have asked question , let see

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code that i have created.

```
var temp = ['3_2', '3_2', '3_2', '4_2', '4_2', '5_2', '5_2' ];
var j = 0;
 this["temp"+j] = [];
for(var i=0; i<temp.length; i++)
{
   var name = temp[i];

   if($.inArray( name,  this["temp"+j]) > -1)
   {

     this["temp"+j].push(name);
   }
   else
   {
        j++;
      this["temp"+j] = [];
        this["temp"+j].push(name);
   }


}
console.log(temp1);
console.log(temp2);
console.log(temp3);
```